# How to get virtualenv to work with fish shell?

Tags: virtualenv, fish

I'm trying to get virtualenv to work with the fish shell. I have virtualenv installed and it works fine with bash and zsh. However, running the following command returns `fish: Unknown command 'source'`:

```
$ source ~/path/to/bin/activate
```

Does anyone know how to get virtualenv and the fish shell to work together?

Comment: I've started to use https://github.com/adambrenecki/virtualfish works very well for my projects.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

You don't need to activate to use virtualenv it is a convenience. You can just use the virtualenv directly:

```
virtualenv venv
./venv/bin/pip install foo
```

---

Have you tried from fish using:

```
. venv/bin/activate.fish
```

It probably isn't as widely used as bash so may have issues - looking at the commit history shows a recent fix:

https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv_embedded/activate.fish

Comment: Thanks. I had tried `active.fish`, but I neeed to update virtualenv to the latest version to get it working.

Comment: If you come across specific bugs please file at http://github.com/pypa/virtualenv Issue tracker

Comment: @Lee I am getting this issue. https://paste.ubuntu.com/25955380/ What does "." here refer to?

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm going to type the full path every time I use something. Sounds great.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia The answer below shows that virtualenv now has a fish activation so you don't need to do that period. Just `source bin/activate.fish`

Answer (score 66):

For virtualenv, fish has a separate activation file in the in the bin directory with `.fish` extension.

So you will have to do:

`$ source ~/path/to/bin/activate.fish`

Comment: This is definitely the way to go for anyone looking at this. The accepted answer is great but it was probably before this was an option.

Comment: PS: the documentation about this command is available in https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment

Answer (score 24):

You can also use this : https://github.com/adambrenecki/virtualfish

It allows you to activate a virtualenv by typing this :

```
vf activate <my_env>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use virtualfish.

> A Fish Shell wrapper for Ian Bicking’s virtualenv, somewhat loosely
>   based on Doug Hellman’s virtualenvwrapper for Bourne-compatible
>   shells.

Source:
https://github.com/adambrenecki/virtualfish

Docs:
http://virtualfish.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use `activate.fish`, you can just add the `bin` directory to your `PATH`:

```
set -gx PATH /path/to/virtualenv/bin $PATH
```

That's pretty much all `activate.fish` does (well, not quite, it also unsets `PYTHONHOME`, (which wasn't set beforehand when I tried it anyway, YMMV); and it tries to mess with your `fish_prompt`).

Alternatively: I'm a former Bash user who's started using Fish and misses Doug Hellman's `virtualenvwrapper`, so I've just today started working on [a replacement called virtualfish](https://github.com/adambrenecki/virtualfish) - it has a few handy shortcuts you might find useful, although it's nowhere near as complete as VEW.

Answer (score 2):

(This thread seems close to be closed, but I found a solution :)

To enter a new fish shell with venv envrionment:

```
begin; set -lx PATH (realpath ./venv)/bin $PATH; fish; end
```

when the venv directory is `./venv`.

To deactivate, just ctrl-d or `exit`.

---

Another solution, which does not invoke a child shell.

Make and enter a venv envrionment:

```
python3 -m venv ./venv
set -lx PATH (realpath ./venv)/bin $PATH
```

Exit from the envrionment:

```
set -lx PATH $PATH[2..-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may can do the same but changes it to:

```
source env/bin/activate.fish
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's an env file try this *.env/bin/activate.fish*
make sure your env file is inside your project file, in my case it's a django project.
Tt worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **command** - `set VIRTUAL_ENV 'path to the virtual env directory'`
Example - `set VIRTUAL_ENV '/home/aman/Desktop/test/venv'`